# Golden Section, Fibonacci and Dichotomic Searches

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I wonder if somebody could quickly and briefly outline some of the similarities and differences between the line search methods [Golden Section Search](http://glossary.computing.society.informs.org/ver2/mpgwiki/index.php/Golden_section_search), [Fibonacci Search](http://glossary.computing.society.informs.org/ver2/mpgwiki/index.php/Fibonacci_search) and [Dichotomic Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomic_search).

I know Dichotomous has two functional evaluations per iteration whereas the other two only one, and that the Fibonacci search tends to the Golden Section as the number of functional evaluates tends to infinity. I know also that you have to predetermine the number of functional evaluates for Fibonacci. Are there other, similar techniques?

Comment: Some links or more complete descriptions would help make your question clearer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_search_technique explains some of the differences.

Comment: Why delete my comments

Comment: only moderators (users with diamond near their username) can delete other people's comments, and they do so when the comments are not relevant to the question. Please see the [FAQ] and [general SE FAQ entry about comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work).

Comment: This question seems to be too broad. Please understand the individual techniques first (and ask focused questions if necessary); you should then be able to compare yourself. If there are problems with the details, you can focus your question.